Memory leak in loop if use tf.lite.interpreter
I am working on a FastAPI project that accepts requests with the model name and data. This data goes through the standard path: (preprocessing, model processing, postprocessing). The interpreter of each model is stored in the dictionary to call the model again.
Since there are a lot of these models (more than 500), the occupied amount of RAM is approaching 3 gigabytes.
I wanted to try to reduce RAM consumption, and tried to remove the tf.lite.interpreter save, but this led to a memory leak. As I understand it, this is due to the fact that tf.lite.interpreter stores some data in memory every time an instance is created.
I would like to know if it is possible to delete all the data created by tf.lite.interpreter after processing. To reduce RAM consumption.
Or is it assumed that tf.lite.interpreter was created for the model and is constantly stored during operation?
Is there any way to free up memory after using the model?
Does my approach make sense?
Thank you in advance for your help. I'm just starting to work with ML.
In the beginning I profiled the memory with memory_profiler. It showed that memory is allocated on the line with tf.lite.Interpreter()
After that I have created a small script for test.
from time import perf_counter, sleep
import tensorflow as tf
import psutil
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler


PATH = ...


rotating_handler = RotatingFileHandler(
    filename='logs/memory_leak.log', 
    mode='a+', 
    maxBytes=int(20e6),
    backupCount=10, 
    encoding='utf-8'
)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
rotating_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
root_logger.addHandler(rotating_handler)

def create_interpreter(path:str):
    with tf.device('/CPU:0'):
        timer_start: float = perf_counter()
        interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=path)
        interpreter.allocate_tensors()
        create_time = perf_counter() - timer_start
        print(f'ID interpreter: {id(interpreter)}')
        print(f'Time: {create_time}')
        process = psutil.Process()
        mem_info = process.memory_info()
        logging.warning(f'Memory usage: RSS={mem_info.rss / 1024 ** 2:.2f} MB, VMS={mem_info.vms / 1024 ** 2:.2f} MB')
        return interpreter

while True:
    some_interpreter = create_interpreter(path=PATH)
    some_interpreter.allocate_tensors()
    sleep(5)
    del some_interpreter

I know that del delete only link but I thought after that python GC clear memory.
According to the logs of this script, the memory consumed by the python process is slowly increasing.

Hi Nick , You are creating a new interpreter for every request .Try to create a pool of interpreters and reusing them.With the help of this you only allocate memory for each model once and manage it in a better way and try to request together so that you can work on multiple input at the same time with the single interpreter.
